# VM provisioning using SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010, virtualization, virtual-machine

Is it possible to do Virtual Machine(VM) provisioning?

Firstly I have a some questions with relation to the above question. How to automate Virtual Machine creation? Is there a software or tool or manually scripting?

How to use SharePoint eform to automatically create VM? 
The eform has the following inputs which is the user's requirements (Virtual Machine(VM) Name, VM operating system, VM memory size, VM disk size).

After entering the inputs, there will be a button (create VM). After clicking, the VM will be created. Using a VMware. we are able to run the VM.

What approach should I take to achieve this using sharepoint and vSphere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a vSphere API expert, but it looks like you should be able to deploy a custom SharePoint solution (web part, system page, user control, etc.) that calls the vSphere web services to provision the VM based on user input to a form.

vSphere API documentation can be found here:  http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/

Comment: is it possible to do scripting using powerCLI scripts to automate VM creation using notepad? or any powerCLI developing tool?

Comment: That is certainly possible, but I'm not sure off hand how you would tie the script back to the SharePoint page you mentioned.  As I mentioned, I'm not a vSphere expert but I've seen integrations done from SharePoint to third party applications based on the method I mentioned above.